# Check if a const of type number is invalid except 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements

I'm checking a number if its null, undefined,..except 0/0.0/0.00 then display value in UI, as shown in below:

```
const currencyFormat = (num) => {
  if(!num) {     // should be true for all cases except 0
    return "0.00"
  }
  return "$"+ num;
}

in render :
 {num === null && <div>
     <h1> {currencyFormat(num)} </h1>
  </div>}
```

How can I display 0/0.0/0.00 because `if !num` is also true for 0?

Comment: If you want to differentiate the number 0 from other falsey values, then `if (!num && num !== 0)`. Where a value is of [Type number](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type), then `0`, `0.0`, and `0.00` are indistinguishable. But it seems to me that if *num* is 0 then "$0.00" should be returned anyway.

Comment: if(num !== undefined && num !== null)

Comment: @subodhkalika—and if `num === false` or `""`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like:

```
const currencyFormat = (num) => {
  const number = parseInt(num);
  if(isNaN(number)) // return whatever you want in case when invalid number(or no number at all)
  if(number === 0) return "0.00";

  return "$"+ num;
}
```